# cakephp updated data with escaping quotes

Tags: json, cakephp, serialization, cakephp-2.0

By using cakephp framework, I have an usual array structure as follows;

```
$myUsualArray = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
```

When I serialized it by using json_encode built in PHP function and update its corresponding field by using saveField function then when I check from DB, the values are as follows;

```
value in DB; "{\"a\":1,\"b\":2,\"c\":3,\"d\":4,\"e\":5}"
```

During field update I just read the id of current table and apply saveField function.

Using: cakephp 2.x

Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly is your problem now? When reading the data and json_decode() it, does the array look like the original again?

Comment: when I decoded it and tried to go through the values by foreach() throws an error

Comment: Display the decoded value here for us. Also: did you disable all those outdated and wrong settings like magic-quotes-gpc?

Comment: It is not event being decoded I mean when I try to decode it and try to loop it, I got - Invalid Argument - warning

Comment: for the ones using php 5.3< JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES can be a solution

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the slashes in the JSON. The way I handle this is using the `beforeSave` and `afterFind` callback methods in the model to do the encoding / decoding.

In the `beforeSave` I do the `json_encode($array)`. In the `afterFind` I do a `preg_replace()` to clean up the slashes and then a `json_decode()`. Then everything is handled cleanly in the model and I never have to worry about it anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by instead of using saveField func, I implemented the save function with custom array values (includes json_encode field) then it saved normally without any slashes and so on